# Apple rejected iOS APP due to redirecting user out of app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes-store, credits

Lets get response from apple team to the below query and update me.

1) Rejection reason: - Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Our APP does not have the option to buy credits within the application in order to redeem an item from the mobile app. If mobile app user require some credits in order to redeem an item from app means, he should buy required credits through using web application alone. Once user buy credits through web application mean, they can utilize those credits in the mobile app while doing any item redeem process.

Does apple team approve the application which have above feature (or) We should implement In App Purchase (IAP) feature in order to approve the above app by apple team? Please provide solution for it.

Comment: As far as I am concerned you must implement iAp. Though, I sometimes see apps that redirect users to a webpage in order to buy items (shirts, mugs, etc.).

Comment: @CeceXX your are allowed to sell non digital goods in your app without IAP. Even redirecting is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to offer any other means for buying digital goods then Apples in app purchase.

You can offer user to buy credits via your site only, but then you may **not** redirect the user to this page from you app. 
There should not be any option within the app that allows to user to buy digital goods via your website.

If possible I would suggest the IAP.